# AlertDialog Styling Issues

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

I'm trying to change the style of an AlertDialog by using the following code :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme));
```

In my styles.xml, I have this style:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="@android:background">#9933CC</item>
    <item name="@android:textColor">#FAF5F7</item>  
    <item name="@android:textSize">5sp</item>
</style>
```

So basically the issues are :

1.- There is a overhead of the background, not limiting it by the AlertDialog frame.

2.- The color of the buttons are not being affected at all.

3.- The textSize does not affect either.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems once with a `ProgressDialog`, it wasn't using the context I passed through the `ContextThemeWrapper`. It should work if you pass the context and the style separately through the constructor:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
```

Comment: I tried that way too, but again, the background color exceeds the size of the Dialog. :(